# How can I sort a vector in a descending order in C?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, swap, bubble-sort

**I have to sort the vector in a descending order, and it doesn't work, this is the algorithm, that I tried to use.**

```
do{
    ok=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(v[i]<v[i+1])    //is the problem here?
    {
            x=v[i];v[i]=v[i+1];v[i+1]=x;
            ok=0;
    }
}while(ok!=0);
```

Comment: what is the number `n`?

Answer (score 2):

The expression in the if statement

```
if(v[i]<v[i+1])
```

can access memory outside the array when `i` is equal to `n - 1`.

You can rewrite the for loop for example the following way

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    if(v[i-1]<v[i])    //is the problem here?
{
        x=v[i-1];v[i-1]=v[i];v[i]=x;
        ok=0;
}
```

A more efficient implementation of the bubble-sort algorithm using your approach can look for example the following way

```
    int m = n;
    do {
        int last = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
            if (v[i-1] < v[i])
            {
                int x = v[i-1]; v[i-1] = v[i]; v[i] = x;
                last = i;
            }
        m = last;
    } while ( !( m < 2 ) );
```